# Flash Builder deactivates breakpoints (sometimes)

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder

For many of my Flash Builder (4.0, 4.5 or 4.6) projects, after a while Flash Builder debugger starts ignoring the breakpoints I placed. When this happens, the breakpoints show up as just a blue dot, instead of a blue dot with a checkmark on it.

All new breakpoints I place after the swf starts, work.

I suspect that it has something to do with the fact that I attach the debugger to a swf running on a server. In the Run/Debug Settings, the url is "http://localhost/xxxxx" instead of direct link to the swf.

As I mention, this doesn't happen all the time. Sometimes, the breakpoints I placed a few hours ago start working.

It is especially annoying when I want to stop at a breakpoint during the initialization.

Anybody has any idea what is causing this and how to get around it?

Thanks.

Comment: We've been having the same issue doing mobile app development with AIR. Breakpoints rarely trigger. It's killing us. Programmers have taken to adding enterDebugger() calls to debug.

It's very annoying Adobe doesn't seem to have addressed this issue. I'm adding my comment to try to bump the question up on Stackoverflow.

We're using Flash Builder 4.6, Flex SDK 3.4. The problem occurs when running in iOS or Android emulators. Any help would be hugely appreciated. This one issue is hugely impacting the quality of our Flash products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've encountered this problem too, and found that the following seems to work:

1. Remove all break points from the app.
2. Do a clean build
3. Start app
4. Set a breakpoint. It should work.

Most of the time you can skip step 2, if it still doesn't work try again including it.

---

We've managed to track the problem to a bug in the Flash debugger. It throws the following exception while starting a run with breakpoints already set:

```
flash.tools.debugger.InProgressException
    at flash.tools.debugger.concrete.DSwfInfo.swdLoaded(DSwfInfo.java:153)
    at flash.tools.debugger.concrete.DSwfInfo.getSourceList(DSwfInfo.java:129)
    at flash.tools.debugger.threadsafe.ThreadSafeSwfInfo.getSourceList(ThreadSafeSwfInfo.java:78)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.breakpoints.FlexLineBreakpoint.findSourceFiles(FlexLineBreakpoint.java:414)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.breakpoints.FlexLineBreakpoint.instantiate(FlexLineBreakpoint.java:467)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexDebugTarget.instantiateBreakpoint(FlexDebugTarget.java:1172)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexDebugTarget.access$4(FlexDebugTarget.java:1166)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexDebugTarget$FdbThread.installDeferredBreakpoints(FlexDebugTarget.java:653)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexDebugTarget$FdbThread.advanceStateMachine(FlexDebugTarget.java:684)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexDebugTarget$FdbThread.access$7(FlexDebugTarget.java:658)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexDebugTarget$FdbThread$1.run(FlexDebugTarget.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexDebugTarget$FdbThread.eventLoop(FlexDebugTarget.java:748)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexDebugTarget$FdbThread.run(FlexDebugTarget.java:812)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: These steps generally work for me, but occasionally do not. I find that restarting Flash Builder between steps 1 and 2 sometimes does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked a fix for this using beyond compare and some due diligence.
This fix is for FB 4.7 and maybe all of 4.x:

in the .metadata for your Flashbuilder workspace open this file:
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs

ensure there is the following line in that file: 
breakpointVerticalRuler=true

FB sometimes writes this entry as: 
breakpointVerticalRuler=true

which is what is causing the issue. FB did this to me when I saved changes in a file while I was remote debugging.